# Firestore - Query via Timestamp doesn´t return results

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna use the Timestamp as a Condition in my Query and end up with the following inside of my Cloud Function:

```
var dateRange = addMinutes(new Date(), 195); // 120 = timezone diff
dateRange = getTime(dateRange);

console.log(dateRange); // --> 1562933996501

const test = await fs.collection('tournaments').doc('B37tIBzDQDFXndv24KHs').get()

console.log(test.data().start); --> Timestamp { _seconds: 1562923800, _nanoseconds: 0 },

const queryRef = fs.collection('tournaments').where('status', '==', '0').where('start', '<=', dateRange);
```

But for some reason the querySnapshot´s size is 0, while the console.logs say that the variable `dateRange = 1562933996501` and the `test` timestamp I query is `1562923800`, so it should be in the area or not?

I use the timestamp field in Firestore for my timestamp. And yes the status of the document is 0.

EDIT trying this out:

```
console.log(test.data().status == 0) // = true
console.log(test.data().start.seconds < dateRange); // = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to query a timestamp type field with an integer.  That won't work.  You can only query timestamps type fields with [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) type objects (as you output shows that you've gotten from the first query).  Or, in JavaScript, you can pass a Date object, which will get converted to a Timestamp automatically.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is as you can see above I actually queried for `status == '0'` but my status is a Number Field, I simply overlooked it and brainafk set the status condition as a String. Because before I had the date object but it did not work so I played around, but the status was the problem. Setting status to a number condition + using a timestamp object made it work

Answer (score 0):

> You can also chain multiple where() methods to create more specific queries (logical AND). **However, to combine the equality operator (==) with a range or array-contains clause (<, <=, >, >=, or array-contains), make sure to create a composite index**.

This is from [firestore's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/querieshttps://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries). Look under "compound queries."

Comment: I have that index created.